# What do you mean by ''Exposing a JSON"

Tags: json, jetty

Just came across a person telling one of my colleagues to use `jetty` with his project and `expose` a `JSON`. Just curious about what it means. I searched the internet but found nothing. So what does it mean to `expose` a `JSON`?
As far as I understand, `jetty` is simply just another `http server` just like `Tomcat` etc. How is `jetty` different and how would it be used to expose a `JSON`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Jetty` is just a server like `Apache's Tomcat` or any other. 
Since nobody has posted an answer on this, `Exposing` a `JSON` merely means receiving the response from a certain webpage (using the `get`method) in the form of a `JSON`. This could also be `XML` for people who would prefer that. 
Browsers like `Chrome` and `Firefox` provide plugins that can be used for the same.
For `Chrome`, one such plugin is `Postman`. Can be added to your browser simply by going to the `Chrome Web Store` and searching for the same.
Hope this helps!